# Android - run a Thread and get a variable value only when thread is finished

Tags: android, multithreading

I need to get a variable value when a thread is finish:

1)Class hello: run a Thread X;

2) Thread X will do something stuff work and set a variable J with some value

3)Class hello: get variable J value after Thread X is finished

Comment: thousands of ways. depends what you want to do with it, but typically a Future<T> from a callable does that. an AsyncTask would be recommended if you intend to use the variable on the UI

Comment: Can u, please, make me an example of those ?

Comment: see doc for `Future` or `AsyncTask` class. what do you do with the variable ? a little more details could help narrow it down

Answer (score 0):

Your existing step "3)" should be broken into two steps:

3) Class hello: join Thread X

4) Class hello: get variable J

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()

Comment: Can u, please, make an example ?

Comment: No.  Now that you know "join" (or "AsyncTask" or "Future<T>" even) is the name of what you are looking for, you should be able to find examples elsewhere on the internet.